# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' and more sililar lines || I do not even reference in my code at all

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a site via a 3rd party webhotel server. I get the following in my error log daily repeatedly, making the error log grow several megabytes every day until I manually delete it. The first time I noticed it, the error log was over a gigabyte in size.

The thing is, I do not recognize any of these items and I do not reference any of them in my code. The server admins said they checked the server and that this is not a serverwide issue, since it only happens on my page.

I have no direct access to the server. I can only use cpanel to look at a few things, but I am no actual admin of the server.

Here is the bulk of the error log, which then repeats over and over:

```
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysql.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysqli.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysqlnd.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.5.6.lin' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dba' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'enchant' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'odbc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'snmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dba' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'enchant' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysql.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd_mysqli.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'odbc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysqlnd.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO_ODBC' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pspell' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'snmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.5.6.lin' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.5.6.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[17-Dec-2020 16:53:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

EDIT: I found a way to access the php.ini, and it has all this stuff in it. This is of course not made by myself, and I have never configured it myself, all came from the provider.
for example, I have no idea what IonCube Loader extension module...

```
; Enable IonCube Loader extension module
[PHP]
zend_extension = "/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so"
extension = bcmath.so
extension = bz2.so
extension = calendar.so
extension = ctype.so
extension = curl.so
extension = dba.so
extension = dom.so
extension = enchant.so
extension = exif.so
extension = fileinfo.so
extension = ftp.so
extension = gd.so
extension = gettext.so
extension = gmp.so
extension = iconv.so
extension = imap.so
extension = intl.so
extension = json.so
extension = ldap.so
extension = mbstring.so
extension = mcrypt.so
extension = mysqlnd.so
extension = mysqlnd_mysql.so
extension = mysqlnd_mysqli.so
extension = odbc.so
extension = pdo.so
extension = pdo_mysqlnd.so
extension = pdo_odbc.so
extension = pdo_pgsql.so
extension = pdo_sqlite.so
extension = pgsql.so
extension = phar.so
extension = posix.so
extension = pspell.so
extension = shmop.so
extension = simplexml.so
extension = snmp.so
extension = soap.so
extension = sockets.so
extension = ixed.5.6.lin
extension = sqlite3.so
extension = sysvmsg.so
extension = sysvsem.so
extension = sysvshm.so
extension = tokenizer.so
extension = xml.so
extension = wddx.so
extension = xmlreader.so
extension = xmlrpc.so
extension = xmlwriter.so
extension = xsl.so
zend_extension = "/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so"
zend_extension = "/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so"
extension = zip.so
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 12
output_buffering = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func = 
serialize_precision = 100
disable_functions = 
disable_classes = 
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 32M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
error_log = error_log
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = On
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file = 
auto_append_file = 
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root = 
user_dir = 
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
default_charset = "UTF-8"
date.timezone = "Europe/Helsinki"
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
date.timezone = "UTC"
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket = 
[Phar]
[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mail.add_x_header = On
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port = 
mysql.default_socket = 
mysql.default_host = 
mysql.default_user = 
mysql.default_password = 
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket = 
mysqli.default_host = 
mysqli.default_user = 
mysqli.default_pw = 
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain = 
session.cookie_httponly = 
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 100
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = On
session.bug_compat_warn = On
session.referer_check = 
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off
[Assertion]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir = "/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[mcrypt]
[dba]
[curl]
```

Comment: They are just warning for default modules, you can either install them, or you can change the log lvl to not include warnings if the size is an issue ?

Comment: It also looks like something it trying to reload some modules.. Do you have some debugging services running ? It could be a cPanel configuration issue..

Comment: `mcrypt` was deprecated in 7.1 and removed in 7.2. Have you built it yourself for 7.4?

Comment: Edit: I see you're a customer, I would contact your provider to see..

Comment: Added php.ini contents, which I found

Comment: Please answer our questions as well, like how you installed mcrypt on PHP 7.4 (since there is no official release for it), or have you upgraded PHP and used an old ini-file?

Comment: Btw, you said you were running this on a webhotel?  Then I would recommend contacting them and ask what has happened.

Comment: Yes. I have not installed anything myself. Just paid for the service and get what they give. The php was initially 5.6 and they have upgraded. I guess they left old ini files.

Comment: Then you should ask them about it, not us. We can't help you debug a server that not even you have access to. If we come with suggestions, you might not even be able to implement them. I would also argue that fixing/debugging a third party hosting companies server are pretty much off-topic here.

Comment: I will. They just told me after 6 months or so to tell me it is a problem with my page and not their issue, and I must fix it myself. So I thought I would ask here. But you are right. This is obviosuly out of my hands.

Answer (score 1):

I manually commented out all those "extension" rows in the php.ini editor. Seems to have stopped the errors from coming in. Thanks for getting me on track that it is indeed some server mistake. It even shows the ini was auto generated by cpanel and must not be edited. But doing this made the issue go away. But I hagve asked the provider to see and tell me what those were doing there in the first place.